# Is there a way to selectively disable pass-through Windows Authentication on an internal website?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

I am building a website that uses Active Directory for authorization. Most of the users will connect to the website using their normal credentials, the ones they are logged into their computer with. Sometimes though, users will need to switch to another account.

I would like to offer those users a link that has the webserver prompt them for their Windows credentials and then pass those to the website for use in the rest of the site. My current alternative is to tell the user to run `chrome.exe --auth-server-allowlist="nothing"` but this requires all other instances of the browser to be closed first so that is not ideal.

The webserver hosting this site will most likely be IIS, so folder specific configurations there would be possible also.

I've been looking for this off and on for some time and have not found a solution. I know I could use basic form-based authentication and then manually verify against AD, but that is also a can of worms I'd rather not open.

Comment: As long as your code returns a 401 response during authentication, the browser will prompt for alternative credentials.

Comment: Normally Windows Authentication automatically uses the credentials of the currently logged in user. You want to use Windows Authentication but still force users to manually enter credentials to authenticate. This behavior is completely opposite to the default behavior of Windows Authentication.